# How to record video from my application using react native?

Tags: react-native

I want to access the camera function through my application. If I click on the record video it should redirect to camera and start to record video. I attached my code. In this code it is redirecting to camera but the video recorder is disabled.

```
recordVideo = async() =>{
        const status = await getPermission(Permissions.CAMERA)
        if(status){
            const result= await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync();
        }
    }

     render(){
        return(

            <View>
                <Text onPress={this.recordVideo}>Record video</Text>

            </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a package for such purpose do check it out, https://github.com/phuochau/react-native-beautiful-video-recorder

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i am not able to use that package also if you know any other plan ,please let me know.

Comment: @MSM, could you let me know how you are not being able to use that package and what problem do you have with it ?

Comment: This package is only for ios itseems But i am Testing on Android Samsung galaxy.@Aashish Karki

Comment: Well, that's a lie. The first sentence on the package says "The video recorder component that extends from react-native-camera. It works for both iOS & Android." so perhaps at least give it a try instead of dismissing it right away? Since it uses react-native-camera I know for a fact it works both on Android and iOS. Just sheer laziness here.

Comment: well @MSM there could me an issue there such as android permission for CAMERA, but it has been resolved in one of the PR https://github.com/phuochau/react-native-beautiful-video-recorder/pull/9/files, other than that I don't think there is a problem in this package do check it

Comment: i am creating experience details page . first i  fill company name , job and start year-end year. then i click on submit button it redirect to next page where we can see the entered details. i want also enter my second company details so if i click on add more button it should go to experience page and i will type the details now both companies information should be present in professional page. how to do that using an array@Aashish Karki

Comment: @MSM, hmm its quite easy as i see it, you should use an array of objects, each object consists of the company details and every time you add push the new object , but i need more context on this matter to give you the exact information, my email is aashish.y2z@gmail.com would be delighted to help you :)

Comment: @ Aashish Karki sure i will email you